# Return and refresh select option value on closest tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I have the below sample code:

```
<table id='myTable'>
 <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Summary</td>
 </tr>
</table>

//Sample document ready function
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTable').dataTable({
      "aoColumnDefs": [
         {
             "aTargets":[1],
             "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                 if(cellData === 'ordered')
                   $(td).css('background-color', '#5cb85c');
                 if(cellData === 'not_ordered') 
                   $(td).css('background-color', '#d9534f');
                 if(cellData === 'shipped')
                   $(td).css('background-color', '#f0ad4e');
             }
         },
         {
            "aTarget": [2],
            "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
               if(type === 'display' && data == null) {
                  data = "enter field summary";
                  return '<input type="text"' + data +'>';
               }
               else
                 return '<input type="text"' + data + '>';
            }
         }
       ]
   });

  //With this function, i want to change the background-color of select field per option selected.However, the val() is returning "undefined"
  $('#myTable').on('change',function(){
     var optionField = $(this).closest('tr').find('option:selected').val();
     if(optionField === 'ordered')
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#696969'});
     else if(optionField === 'notOrdered')
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#e7e7e7'});
     else(optionField === 'shipped')
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#326f3a'});
  }

  $('table').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e)){
     var url = 'hiddenAPI.com';
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: "POST",
         async: true,
         data: {
             id:      idField,
             status:  statusField,
             summary: summaryField
         },
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data){
            $('#responseField').html('Order ' + idField + ', summary has been posted to the database successfully');
            $('#myTable').ajax.reload(); //<- table not refreshing here
         },
     });
  });

});
```

With the above code, I want to change the background color everytime a select option is selected (determined per value in the code above), also after every post to the database, I want to refresh the whole datatable with the new JSON data. So far the API provided on the datatable site (table.ajax.reload()) isn't working.

Two questions, 
1.) With my code above, how can I change the background color of a specific column in datatable after select option is selected? 
2.) How do I refresh datatable after every post to the database without having to refresh the entire window/page?

Comment: Well for a start you have a missing single quote at the end of the `#table` selector `$('#myTable).on('change',function(){` which will result in syntax errors appearing in your browser console.

Comment: Why has someone other than the OP changed the source code....

Comment: @NewToJS that was just my typo. The entire code checks with no browser errors. The code above is a snippet from my code at large, so it might have been a closed single quote I forgot to add.

Comment: @NewToJS, agree, a whole edit just for inserting a single quote `'` ...? It does not make sense. It *could* be the cause of problem, more likely just a typo OP probably is well aware of.

Comment: I understand sometimes people make mistakes when one is adding the source code to the question but for someone else to change it is purely based off their assumption. The source code should not be altered/corrected unless stated by the OP of a genuine mistake or difficulties displaying the relevant information.

Comment: Guys, I have modified my code above to avoid confusion of any syntax errors. The above code should be free from any syntax errors. Again, my code is more of a logic question, rather than browser syntax errors (which there is none on my end). Copying snippet of codes on here, can result to typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, I ended up fixing this myself.
1.) to refresh ajax data, I ended up calling another ajax call (from another primary function) inside the done function.

2.) to click and return the closest selected option in a table row, I ended up first creating an on click function on the table, and then nested another function for the select on change, then used $(this).closest('tr).find('select').val().

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
$(this).css({background-color':'#696969'});
     else if(optionField === 'notOrdered')
        $(this).css({background-color':'#e7e7e7'});
     else(optionField === 'shipped')
        $(this).css({background-color':'#326f3a'});
  }
```

the "background-color" string is missing an extra ' at the start

edit: sorry, only fixed a syntax error